# How to show connections between local and remote branches in git?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, remote-branch

I'd like to add a copy of a remote branch (`origin/featureX`) to my local repository.

Therefore I generated a local branch `featureX` and set it to track the given remote branch:

```
git branch featureX
git branch -u origin/featureX featureX
# Branch featureX set up to track remote branch featureX from origin.
```

Now is there a way to show this connection? I tried e.g. `git branch -av`, but no connection between `featureX` and `remotes/origin/featureX` are shown.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to be more verbose `git branch -vv`, this is [documented](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) but not obvious.

> -v
>   -vv
>   --verbose
>   When in list mode, show sha1 and commit subject line for each head, along with relationship to upstream branch (if any). **If given twice, print the name of the upstream branch, as well** (see also git remote show ).

Answer (score 4):

To see the linkage easily, double the `-v` option:

```
$ git branch -v
* master   b9a3e01 [ahead 3]
$ git branch -vv
* master   b9a3e01 [origin/master: ahead 3]
```

See [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32518376/1256452) for a more convenient way to get these things started, in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of [`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch), try a `git checkout featureX`.
Since there is an `origin/featureX` branch, that local branch would be linked automatically to the remote tracking one.

Delete your branch first, and recreate it:

```
git branch -d featureX
git checkout featureX
```

From [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to

```
$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

Comment: Thanks, ... using `git checkout` does in fact make more sense.

Comment: @Edward yes, that way, you know that your local branch starts from the right commit (`origin/featureX`)